# Syntax error in Update statement with Case Calculations

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016, ssms-2016

I am trying to calculate percentage pay for drivers based on if the order is in multiple segments, or a single segment based on the type of driver. I successfully test each part but the From has a red underline and I get a syntax error when I execute it. Here is the script I am attempting:

```
update legheader
set lgh_extrainfo1 =  ( 
Select Case  When L.lgh_split_flag <> 'N' and L.lgh_carrier = 'UNKNOWN'
       Then Case 
            When 
            TR.trc_type1 = 'O/O' and TR.trc_type3 = '70Per'
            Then CAST (.7 * ((Cast (L.lgh_miles as decimal (10,2))/O.ord_totalmiles) * L.lgh_ord_charge)as decimal (10,2))
            When 
            TR.trc_type1 = 'O/O' and TR.trc_type3 <> '70Per'
            Then CAST (.64 * ((Cast (L.lgh_miles as decimal (10,2))/O.ord_totalmiles) * L.lgh_ord_charge)as decimal (10,2))


            When L.lgh_split_flag = 'N' and L.lgh_carrier = 'UNKNOWN' 
            Then Case
            When  
            TR.trc_type1 = 'O/O' and TR.trc_type3 = '70Per'
            Then CAST (.7 * L.lgh_ord_charge as decimal (10,2))
            When 
            TR.trc_type1 = 'O/O' and TR.trc_type3 <> '70Per'
            Then CAST (.64 * L.lgh_ord_charge as decimal (10,2))


        End    

From Legheader L Left Join TractorProfile TR on L.lgh_tractor = TR.trc_number
                 Left Join Orderheader O on O.ord_hdrnumber = L.ord_hdrnumber)
```

Comment: I see three `CASE` but only one `END`.

Comment: I thought you could have multiple When and Then, and only needed one End.

Comment: You can have multiple `WHEN/THEN` within a single `CASE`, but you have nested 2 more `CASE` within the outer one. They need to be closed themselves before the outer can be closed with `END`.

Comment: Will that hamper trying to get a single calculation in the end? or will that produce more than a single result such as NULL's?

Comment: I added the End to each nested Case, and that took away the red underline under the From, but when I execute I now get Invalid Object Name 'Legheader' any ideas why, it doesn't have any red marks anywhere?

Comment: Case sensitivity? I don't know how SQL Server manages table (object) names, but I have seen other posts referring to the database level collation affecting table name case.  Why not just type the correct case all the time `legheader` vs `Legheader`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query. Here you are missed the `END` statement for the nested `CASE`.

```
update legheader
set lgh_extrainfo1  =  ( 
Select Case  
When L.lgh_split_flag <> 'N' and L.lgh_carrier = 'UNKNOWN'
       Then 
       Case 
            When 
            TR.trc_type1 = 'O/O' and TR.trc_type3 = '70Per'
            Then CAST (.7 * ((Cast (L.lgh_miles as decimal (10,2))/O.ord_totalmiles) * L.lgh_ord_charge)as decimal (10,2))
            When 
            TR.trc_type1 = 'O/O' and TR.trc_type3 <> '70Per'
            Then CAST (.64 * ((Cast (L.lgh_miles as decimal (10,2))/O.ord_totalmiles) * L.lgh_ord_charge)as decimal (10,2))
         END
When L.lgh_split_flag = 'N' and L.lgh_carrier = 'UNKNOWN' 
         Then 
            Case
                When  
                TR.trc_type1 = 'O/O' and TR.trc_type3 = '70Per'
                Then CAST (.7 * L.lgh_ord_charge as decimal (10,2))
                When 
                TR.trc_type1 = 'O/O' and TR.trc_type3 <> '70Per'
                Then CAST (.64 * L.lgh_ord_charge as decimal (10,2))
            END

        End    

From Legheader L Left Join TractorProfile TR on L.lgh_tractor = TR.trc_number
                 Left Join Orderheader O on O.ord_hdrnumber = L.ord_hdrnumber)
```